# vaadin CheckBoxGroup does not render

Tags: java, spring-boot, frontend, vaadin, vaadin14

My program can add or update profiles. In the update profile dialog, after selecting which profile u want to update. Fields should fill with selected profile values. The problem starts with filling the CheckboxGroup field. (My CheckboxGroup field name is listBox so after that I'm gonna call it that way). when I check my listBox selected items I can see the listBox selected values are true but in the frontend, I can't see any selection. So basically I want to reselect lists in addValueChangeListener but CheckboxGroup not rerendering.

```
listBox = new CheckboxGroup<>();
listBox.setItemLabelGenerator(Lists::getListName);
listBox.setItems();
listBox.setItems(listsList);
listBox.addThemeVariants(CheckboxGroupVariant.LUMO_VERTICAL);
listBox.setHeight("200px");
listBox.getStyle().set("overflow","AUTO");
listBox.setHelperText("Seçilen Listeler");
listBox.addThemeVariants(CheckboxGroupVariant.LUMO_HELPER_ABOVE_FIELD);

updateProfile.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
        setUpdateProfileValues();
    });
}

private void setUpdateProfileValues() {
    if (updateProfile.getValue() == null)
        return;
    updateProfileName.setValue(updateProfile.getValue().getProfileName());
    simAlgorithm.setValue(updateProfile.getValue().getSimAlgorithm());
    searchType.setValue(updateProfile.getValue().getSearchType());
    operationType.setValue(updateProfile.getValue().getOperatorType());
    simPercentage.setValue(updateProfile.getValue().getSimPercentage());
    numberOfResult.setValue(updateProfile.getValue().getNumberOfResults());
    List<Lists> selectedLists = updateProfile.getValue().getLists();
    selectedLists.forEach(lists -> log.error(lists.getListName()));
    //selectedLists.forEach(listBox::select);
    listBox.setValue(new HashSet<>(selectedLists));
    listBox.getSelectedItems().forEach(selectedList -> log.error(selectedList.getListName()));

}
```

Here is my related code piece for this question. BTW when I check the logs I can see listBox has true selected values. But I need to show on frontend page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a quick piece of code using your listBox initialization and I was able to set all of the Checkboxes to true on the front end. This might help you:

```
listBox.getChildren().filter(Checkbox.class::isInstance)
            .map(Checkbox.class::cast)
            .forEach(c -> c.setValue(true));
```

This retrieves all the Checkboxes within the CheckboxGroup, checks that they are an instance of the Vaadin Checkbox component, and then sets their T/F value as desired.

Comment: Actually I found the problem. As you can see my checkBoxGroup holding items as Objects(Lists object). When I click the buttons the given object has the same values but it is not the same object that's why it keeping data but not changing the frontend because its looking for the same object. I figure it out with adding equals method to Lists object model. But I guess your way will be the second option to solve a problem. I will accept it for your helping. Thank you.

Comment: good catch with the .equals call - my assumption was that the issue was with the CheckBox component itself, rather than the associated list of objects.